# good way for reading a delimited file into DataTable

Tags: c#

i was looking for good way to read a delimited file into DataTable and found this piece of code.

```
    private void txtRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var filename = @"d:\shiptest.txt";
        var reader = ReadAsLines(filename);

        var data = new DataTable();

        //this assume the first record is filled with the column names
        var headers = reader.First().Split('\t');
        foreach (var header in headers)
        {
            data.Columns.Add(header);
        }

        var records = reader.Skip(1);
        foreach (var record in records)
        {
            data.Rows.Add(record.Split('\t'));
        }

        dgList.DataSource=data;
    }

    static IEnumerable<string> ReadAsLines(string filename)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(filename))
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                yield return reader.ReadLine();
    }
```

this code works fine and fast but i am curious about that what would be the efficiency of the above code when there will be huge data in text file.looking for suggestion. thanks

Comment: Possible alternative would be to read the whole file into a string and split it by \r\n.

Comment: Or yet another alternative would be to use a ready-made third-party solution like [FileHelpers 2.0](http://www.filehelpers.com) instead of yet again re-inventing the wheel ..

Comment: @marc_s, IMO importing a whole library to replace 2 methods is a bit overkill.

Comment: Thomas- Your method is very fast. Faster than some of the leading free third-party. To read a comma delimited file of about 14,000 records into  DataTable, FileHelpers took more than 60 seconds , but your method did it in the blink of an eye. So, stop believing these guys who say to use third-party stuff, and are forever saying ' why re-invent'.

Comment: Try File.ReadAllLines(filename).ToList(); instead of ReadAsLines method.